# Birthday and Marriage Information

Tags: data-request, census

I'm interested in marriage/divorce information by birth date.

Does anyone know the best place to get something like that?

Answer (score 3):

Something like [this](http://www.theguardian.com/news/datablog/2013/jun/07/world-divorce-rates-putin-perspective#data)?

You can find the spreadsheet on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3):

There's are a number of studies on various 'birthday effects' in economics literature. I don't know of any that use open data, but you could contact the authors for help in your research.

Here's an example from the genre. http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2241677