# dataset with date of birth of both partners and date of marriage/divorce

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a dataset with the date of birth of both partners and the date of marriage/divorce. The reason why is to generate the zodiacal sign of both partners.

Comment: Is this similar to http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1221/birthday-and-marriage-information

Answer (score 0):

There is dataset on Kaggle - "[Divorce/marriage dataset with birth dates](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aagghh/divorcemarriage-dataset-with-birth-dates)".